# React Native make items responsive

Tags: javascript, react-native, flexbox, width

[Example between correct and incorrect item stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hki8n.jpg)

Please refere to the image. I have twee phones one with a screen width of 1440px and one with 1080px.On the 1440 screen the items are stacked in a two column structure. On the 1080 everything gets stacked on the left column. Is there a way to write a javascript function that looks at the device width and sets the item to adjust accordingly?

```
const Complex = () => {
return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <CarouselCards />
        <Divider
            style={{
                color: 'black',
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                marginHorizontal: 15,
            }}
        />
        <ScrollView horizontal={false}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
                {KPI.map((item) => (
                    <View style={styles.cardContainer} key={item.id}>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                            <View
                                style={{
                                    flex: 1,
                                    flexWrap: 'wrap',
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={styles.cardContent}>
                                    <Text style={styles.cardTitle}>{item.title}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.bigFatNumber}>{item.value}</Text>
                                    <Text style={styles.smallKPI}>{item.kpi}</Text>
                                    <View style={{display:' flex'}}>

                                    <BarChart
                                        style={{ height: 100, width: 130 }}
                                        data={barData}
                                        svg={{ fill }}
                                        contentInset={{ top: 1, bottom: 30 }}
                                    ></BarChart>
                                    </View>

                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                ))}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
)
```

export default Complex

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
cardContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: 168,
    height: 190,
    margin: 15,
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.29,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,
    elevation: 7,
    padding: 15,
},
chartContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: 168,
    height: '100%',
    margin: 15,
    borderRadius: 8,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.29,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,
    elevation: 7,
    padding: 15,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    display: 'flex',
},
cardTitle: {
    // letterSpacing: 0.25,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize: 14,
},
cardContent: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    gap: 6,
    paddingVertical: 5,
},
bigFatNumber: {
    letterSpacing: 0.25,
    lineHeight: 36,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize: 24,
},
smallKPI: {
    letterSpacing: 0.25,
    lineHeight: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize: 14,
    order: 1,
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
},
```

})

Comment: Please share your code so people can help you easily. Also rather using fix width for view use flex or you have to get width of screen and then you have to divide it and use it in you view.

Comment: i just did add the code :)

Comment: Remove width: 168, and add flex: 1 and check

Answer (score 0):

You can get device-width with Dimensions that you get in React native - https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions. Yust add your items fixed width(something like (width-yourMargin) / 3) or you can use flex and not use fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

1. use

[react-native-responsive-dimensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions)

**use key word npm install  for windows**

```js
npm i react-native-responsive-dimensions
```

2. **import using that**

```js
import {
  responsiveHeight as rh,
  responsiveWidth as rw,
  responsiveFontSize as rf,
} from "react-native-responsive-dimensions";
```

3. **how to use**

```js
width:rw(100),
height:rh((100),
fontSize:rf(1.5),
```